# Subclass of Combobox doesn't support filtering in vaadin

Tags: combobox, filtering, vaadin

It's a common practice to subclass a ComboBox component in vaadin because it lacks setting pageLength functionality in a standard API.

The problem is that setting filteringMode doesn't work with a subclass. I've tried a simple code with ComboBox with FILTERINGMODE_STARTSWITH, it worked perfectly, the same code with the custom class - doesn't work(filtering is not working, all items are shown anyway).

Why could this problem happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in pageLength parameter. If it's set to zero, then filtering doesn't work. I've set it to a big number so that it behaves the same as with zero and everything works fine.

Comment: I have to ask, how did you figure this one out? And thank you, you probably saved me hours of work!!